# Office 2010 can't open folder at my Skydrive

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, online-storage

I followed the steps to upload documents to a folder at Microsofts Skydrive.
Backstage,Share,Save to skydrive,(at this point it always shows Sorry, we are unable to connect to Skydrive.) Than I click the Try Again button and It connects. Then I click the folder I wish to put the document into. And click Save As. And I get (Could not open *url*). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. It looks like Office 2010 is still beta in this case. I mean, internal tests surely worked but they do not want to enable it yet.
However it could be that it is a country restricted feature. (like bing.com-s full feature list only works in English (US) )

Comment: However under Office 2007, Office Live Spaces or something like that works perfectly for me. It has 5GB free storage for your Word, Excel, PowerPoint contents.

Comment: Do you use the live.com for your e-mail? I used an outlook connector to the live.com for my e-mail.

Comment: Not live.com, ... Office Live. Here: http://workspace.officelive.com/en-us/